# How to align multiple equation with numbereing each equation

Tags: equations, align

I've tried the answer of similar question but doesn't work.

```
\begin{equation}\label{pertama0}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{10}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{x}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2(x-\hat{x})\\
&=2(\hat{x}-x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L^o_{10}}{\partial L^i_{10}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{10})}{\partial L^i_{10}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{10}}{\partial L^i_{10}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L_{10}^{i}}{\partial a_{21}} &=\frac{\partial\left(x_{n}+h\left(b_{1} k_{1x}+b_{2}k_{2x}\right)\right.}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=\frac{\partial\left(h b_{2} k_{2 x}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2}\frac{ \partial\left(x_{n}^{\prime}+h a_{21} k_{1x^{\prime}})\right.}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h^{2} b_{2} k_{1 x^{\prime}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{11}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{y}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2(y-\hat{y})\\
&=2(\hat{y}-y)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L^o_{11}}{\partial L^i_{11}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{11})}{\partial L^i_{11}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{11}}{\partial L^i_{11}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L_{11}^{i}}{\partial a_{21}} &=\frac{\partial\left(y_{n}+h\left(b_{1} k_{1y}+b_{2}k_{2y}\right)\right.}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=\frac{\partial\left(h b_{2} k_{2 y}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2}\frac{ \partial\left(y_{n}^{\prime}+h a_{21} k_{1y^{\prime}})\right.}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h^{2} b_{2} k_{1 y^{\prime}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{12}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{x}^{\prime}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2({x}^{\prime}-\hat{x}^{\prime})\\
&=2(\hat{x}^{\prime}-{x}^{\prime})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L^o_{12}}{\partial L^i_{12}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{12})}{\partial L^i_{12}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{12}}{\partial L^i_{12}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L_{12}^{i}}{\partial a_{21}} &=\frac{\partial\left(x_{n}^{\prime}+h\left(b_{1} k_{1x^{\prime}}+b_{2}k_{2 x^{\prime}}\right)\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=\frac{\partial\left(h b_{2} k_{2 x^{\prime}}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2} \frac{\partial f_{x^\prime}\left(x_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 x^{\prime}}, y_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2}\left(f_{x^{\prime}_{1}} h k_{1x^{\prime}} +f_{x^{\prime}_{2}} h k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{13}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{y}^{\prime}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2({y}^{\prime}-\hat{y}^{\prime})\\
&=2(\hat{y}^{\prime}-{y}^{\prime})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L^o_{13}}{\partial L^i_{13}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{13})}{\partial L^i_{13}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{13}}{\partial L^i_{13}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{terakhhir0}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L_{13}^{i}}{\partial a_{21}} &=\frac{\partial\left(y_{n}^{\prime}+h\left(b_{1} k_{1y^{\prime}}+b_{2}k_{2 y^{\prime}}\right)\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=\frac{\partial\left(h b_{2} k_{2 y^{\prime}}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2} \frac{\partial f_{y^\prime}\left(x_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 x^{\prime}}, y_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2}\left(f_{y^{\prime}_{1}} h k_{1x^{\prime}} +f_{y^{\prime}_{2}} h k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{13}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{y}^{\prime}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2({y}^{\prime}-\hat{y}^{\prime})\\
&=2(\hat{y}^{\prime}-{y}^{\prime})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L^o_{13}}{\partial L^i_{13}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{13})}{\partial L^i_{13}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{13}}{\partial L^i_{13}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{terakhhir0}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L_{13}^{i}}{\partial a_{21}} &=\frac{\partial\left(y_{n}^{\prime}+h\left(b_{1} k_{1y^{\prime}}+b_{2}k_{2 y^{\prime}}\right)\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=\frac{\partial\left(h b_{2} k_{2 y^{\prime}}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2} \frac{\partial f_{y^\prime}\left(x_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 x^{\prime}}, y_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2}\left(f_{y^{\prime}_{1}} h k_{1x^{\prime}} +f_{y^{\prime}_{2}} h k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

 
\begin{equation}\label{pertama0}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{10}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{x}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2(x-\hat{x})\\
&=2(\hat{x}-x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L^o_{10}}{\partial L^i_{10}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{10})}{\partial L^i_{10}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{10}}{\partial L^i_{10}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L_{10}^{i}}{\partial a_{21}} &=\frac{\partial\left(x_{n}+h\left(b_{1} k_{1x}+b_{2}k_{2x}\right)\right.}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=\frac{\partial\left(h b_{2} k_{2 x}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2}\frac{ \partial\left(x_{n}^{\prime}+h a_{21} k_{1x^{\prime}})\right.}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h^{2} b_{2} k_{1 x^{\prime}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{11}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{y}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2(y-\hat{y})\\
&=2(\hat{y}-y)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L^o_{11}}{\partial L^i_{11}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{11})}{\partial L^i_{11}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{11}}{\partial L^i_{11}}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Wondering like this [image]

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Do link to any similar questions you have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `align` with `split`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{first}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{10}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{x}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2(x-\hat{x})\\
&=2(\hat{x}-x)
\end{split}
\\[1ex]
\begin{split}\label{second}
\frac{\partial L^o_{10}}{\partial L^i_{10}}&= \frac{\partial f(L^i_{10})}{\partial L^i_{10}}\\
&=\frac{\partial L^i_{10}}{\partial L^i_{10}}\\
&=1
\end{split}
\\[1ex]
\begin{split}\label{third}
\frac{\partial L_{10}^{i}}{\partial a_{21}} &=\frac{\partial(x_{n}+h(b_{1} k_{1x}+b_{2}k_{2x}))}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=\frac{\partial(h b_{2} k_{2 x})}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h b_{2}\frac{ \partial(x_{n}'+h a_{21} k_{1x'})}{\partial a_{21}} \\
&=h^{2} b_{2} k_{1 x'}
\end{split}
\\[1ex]
\begin{split}\label{fourth}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L^0_{11}}&= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{y}_{n+1}}\\
&=-2(y-\hat{y})\\
&=2(\hat{y}-y)
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Between blocks I used `\\[1ex]` that adds some vertical space that helps the  reader in better seeing the block boundaries.

I removed the useless `\left` and `\right` instructions: in those cases they just added unwanted space. I also changed `^{\prime}` into the simpler `'`.

Check the suspicious `^o` that should probably be `^0`.

[image]